# How to correctly Public and Set a Worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Public sp As Worksheet  //  on top of ThisWorkbook module
...
Sub one()
Set sp = Sheets("blueSky")  // marked
MsgBox sp.Name
...
Sub two()
Set sp = Sheets("blueSky")  //  marked
MsgBox sp.Range("A1").Value
```

Marked line is allways the same.
So, is it possible to write the marked line only once - and where ?
I tried on Workbook.Open event - without result
I want in each Sub write only the third line - which is allways different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put the followin in a module (not `ThisWorkbook`) you get a global `Worksheet` variable:

```
Option Explicit

Global sp As Worksheet
```

You can then adress it in any of the following ways in `ThisWorkbook` (subs `one()` and `two()` will also work in a module):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub one()
    Set sp = Sheets("Sheet1")  '// marked
    MsgBox sp.Name
End Sub

Sub two()
    Set sp = Sheets("Sheet2") ' //  marked
    MsgBox sp.Range("A1").Value
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set sp = Sheets("Sheet3")
End Sub
```

Comment: Olle, I want `Set sp = Sheets("Sheet1")` write only once, somewhere. This is allways the same line, on each of my Subs. In your example, it is set three times on three different Sheets. But this is not my case. I want not to write allways the same line, on each sub.

Comment: OK, then use only `Workbook_Open()` in `ThisWorkbook`. It will run once, when the Workbook is opened. In order to use a global variable you need to declare it in a module.

Comment: I already wrote `Set sp = Sheets("blueSky")` in Workbook_Open(). And tried tu run `MsgBox sp.Name` from a module - it doesnt work. Error is - Object required !

Comment: Did you put `Global sp As Worksheet` in a module? You cannot have a global variable in `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: Also, if you put `Option Explicit` at the top, you minimize the problem with misspelled variable names.

Comment: Also, anything you want to do with the `sp` variable, you can do with `Sheets("blueSky")` directly, like `MsgBox Sheets("blueSky").Name`. No need for a variable, really.

Comment: Olle, I'm trying not to write hundred of times `Sheets("blueSky")` instead just `sp`. I will try your above sugestions. Thanks a lot.